# Sometimes PowerShell stops sending output until I press enter. Why?

Tags: powershell

Periodically I notice PowerShell seems to take forever to finish doing whatever it is I told it to do until it occurs to me to "wake it up" by pressing enter. This is not the fault of any one process as best I can tell, as I have even run custom apps that just log their output to the screen every few seconds and even in these cases, PowerShell will stop doing anything after a while until I "give it a kick" by pressing enter.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: Wow! This also applies to the new (silently installed) windows console!

Comment: Happens in the Ubunto On Windows console as well.

Answer (score 202, accepted):

If the `QuickEdit Mode` and\or `Insert` options are checked within the console\window properties, and you click within the console, it will pause the output. If those options are not checked, the output can't be paused by clicking within the console.

[image]
To get to these settings, right-click on the PowerShell-Logo in the top-left of your terminal window, then select 'Properties' (at least that's one way to do it)

Comment: Ah, yes, it never occurred to me that clicking the screen could interrupt the output. After running some tests, this indeed seems to be the issue.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: You are my hero!

Comment: OMG Shell fail.

Comment: That is extremely annoying :) Another undocumented feature?

Comment: literally joined server fault to upvote, been years since i observed it first time, but it never became problem big enough to look into, until today i stepped on this 'rake' again :)

Comment: This same issue (and solution) apply for the CMD terminal in Windows as well.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30418886/how-and-why-does-quickedit-mode-in-command-prompt-freeze-applications

Comment: Like drk, I joined this site to upvote :D. This solved one of the most annoying mysteries in my life lol.

Comment: Another hilariously ill-conceived and undocumented misfeature.  Microsoft never ceases to both irritate and amaze me.

Comment: How annoying. I wonder who thought this was a good default behaviour >:(

Comment: Annoying, but so useful at the same time. OMG, how often I tried copying some error's, and missed it due to fast terminal updates.

Comment: I posted a similar question on SO, thinking it was Python's fault. But somebody directed me here, and this was the answer I sought. Thanks!

Comment: Just joined this site to upvote. I thought it was some threading issue in my code! LOL

Comment: I'm aware of the left click issue, but I have a system pausing where it stops hanging a few minutes after the window loses focus. It's very odd. And only on one computer, the rest are fine.

Comment: @s.meijer it's true this behavior is a solution to the problem of output scrolling past. however a much less invasive solution would seem to be to halt just the _scrolling_ rather than the actual execution.

Comment: @CurtM if i could i would buy you a case of beer. this is the DUMBEST "feature" i have ever heard of. just like the other commenters it happened randomly and i figured it was just a bug. christ the MS logic is just baffling to include something so asinine, let alone to do so without documenting it.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. Note: actually, pressing any character (not only "Enter") will unpause the execution.

Comment: Not only does it stops the output, but when running scripts to install Windows features, it pauses that too. I must have stared at my screen for 30 minutes waiting thinking the installation was frozen until I realized it was paused because I accidentally clicked in the terminal... This should really be more obvious!

Comment: Is there a way to disable this feature in the code?  Users are gonna blame me if they accidently click on the console and the script stops

Comment: That is the problem we face. Hopefully Microsoft will add this parameter adjustment feature when opening the command line window via cli

Answer (score 1):

If you are running PowerShell script from within Cygwin like so:

```
powershell.exe -Command '<...>'
```

and you get this problem, you can fix it by piping in a newline:

```
echo | powershell.exe -Command '<...>'
```