# Windows Powershell requires me to press Enter after the command finishes

Tags: windows, powershell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sometimes PowerShell stops sending output until I press enter. Why?](https://serverfault.com/questions/204150/sometimes-powershell-stops-sending-output-until-i-press-enter-why)

I am executing powershell commands like: powershell.exe "Get-Process java | Stop-Process"
and when the command finishes it is requiring me to press Enter before returning me to the console.

Is there a way of executing a command so that I dont have to press enter to be returned to the console?

Answer (score 1):

Do you get a confirmation message like this one:

```
Confirm
Are you sure you want to perform this action?
Performing operation "Stop-Process" on Target "java (xxxx)".
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):
```

Generally, you can suppress confirmations with this:

```
Get-Process java | Stop-Process -Confirm:$false
```

Comment: There is no confirmation dialog, and even a simple script like: powershell.exe -noprofile -NonInteractive -Command "exit 10" will not even exit after running.
The console just hangs until I press enter.