# powershell script waits for printing output until I press a button

Tags: windows-server-2008, powershell

I wrote a PS1 script that will count how many processes (in this case MS Project) are running on a Citrix farm.

The code it's:

```
$variable=(query farm /process | where { $_.Contains("WINPROJ") }  | measure ).count
echo $variable
```

If I execute the PS1 from powershell, it works flawlessly but If I invoke it from cmd (for schedule it) using 
powershell.exe -file "C:\foo\countProcessProject.ps1" or powershell.exe -c "C:\foo\countProcessProject.ps1" the script will stop until I press a button multiple times, outputting the variable.

I've compared environment variables on CMD and PS execution and are almost the same.

Greets,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to force it to return using the `-NonInteractive` argument with powershell:

```
PowerShell.exe -File "C:\foo\countProcessProject.ps1" -NonInteractive
```

While I have no insightful explanation as to why this would be necessary, here is how I would work around this issue:

### Without PowerShell:

If you insist on using the archaeological gem of `query farm`, this can be done using `cmd` alone - no need to complicate a simple task:

```
query farm /process |find /i "winproj" /c
```

This will output the number "winproj" processes much in the same way as your current powershell invocation statement

### Using just PowerShell:

If you are keen on moving on to a more PowerShell-centric solution, you can use the PS Snapins included in the offical  [XenApp PowerShell SDK](https://www.citrix.com/downloads/xenapp/sdks/powershell-sdk.html) from Citrix:

```
Add-PSSnapin Citrix.XenApp.Commands
$FarmProcs = Get-XAServer -OnlineOnly | Get-XASessionProcess
$MSProjProcs = $FarmProcs | Where {ProcessName -match "winproj"} | Measure-Object
return $MSProjProcs.Count
```

Comment: It works, and I love the use of the powershell cmdlets (I didn't know about the XA PS SDK... now on bookmarks for future scripts).

Comment: The XenApp cmdlets are not super versatile, but they work and they ease the pain of wrapping commandline management. Glad to hear it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I'll in first place try to put this :

```
PowerShell.exe -file "C:\foo\countProcessProject.ps1"
```

In a batch file and then create a Schedule Task that runs this batch which will run your Powershell script.

Assuming you've not already tried this.

Comment: I tried again calling the script via bat file & task scheduler, same result. Until I press any keyboard button it keeps freezed

Answer (score 0):

Does it work when you use the start /b command to spawn powershell inside the cmd console.

```
start /b /wait Powershell.exe -file "C:\foo\countProcessProject.ps1"
```

Can you confirm you are not clicking anywhere on the screen during the script enabling the click pause as [described here.](https://serverfault.com/questions/204150/sometimes-powershell-stops-sending-output-until-i-press-enter-why)

Comment: Yeah, tried this too and it doesn't works. I disabled the quick edition mode on cmd by default

Answer (score 0):

I'm still learning PowerScript and don't have the points to comment above, but have been looking at this and have some questions.  Hope you will indulge me.

First I can create a simple test file and run it from cmd like this:

```
$v = (dir | Where-Object { $_.name.Contains("test") } | measure).count
echo $v
```

I run this in cmd with:

```
powershell -file test.ps1
```

It takes a moment but then returns 1 because my file is test.ps1

---

What is the 'query farm /process' ?  Is this an external command?  And what does it return?  I think the pipe following it is expecting an array, is it not?  I'm wondering what happens to errors when you run from cmd.  I do know that a 2> command line suffix null will cleanly get rid of any error.

Comment: So I had a little time to think about this, and if you get the chance please run the script I wrote above as a test.  It will be interesting if it too has the same trouble, because it does not have that trouble here.

Comment: query farm /process it's a Citrix command for list all XenApp's farm processes. The script you've wrote works without problems from CMD and also from task scheduler

Comment: humm?  Then there appears to be something strange about query farm /process, like it's stopping and asking for standard input or something, or a batch file, or checking some env variable, or something strange.  ??

Comment: It seems, but in a Powershell windows the .PS1 runs without problem. I'll try on another approach